# How to to verify any mdadm RAID array is doing fine

Tags: linux, mdadm, software-raid

Is there something like:

```
mdadm --verify <device>
```

Or similar command, which would read all sectors of all drives of a [Software RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Software-based) array in any [`mdadm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm) implemented RAID to verify the array is doing just fine?

Please include important steps like the need of un-mounting the array if applicable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
echo check > /sys/block/mdX/md/sync_action
```

This will force the MD subsystem to perform a check of `/dev/mdX`.

This is what `checkarray` does eventually, after a number of extra checks. The above also works on systems without such a utility.

Note that with a mounted filesystem the check nearly always give a number of inconsistent blocks.

Remember to unmount the filesystem first, if possible, to avoid those inconsistencies.

*Note, that the above command can be particularly useful for newly created arrays, which `checkarray` skips.*

Comment: i question the need to unmount the filesystem to run a check. for one this is rarely practical. servers need to keep operating, and may even be impossible if root is on raid too (unless booted from an external media). further, i doubt that mdadm will find errors because blocks would be inconsistent. since it is mdadm that is responsible for keeping those blocks consistent, it surely can tell during the check if a block just happens the be written right now. debian is running this check monthly from cron.it would be rather useless if it would find errors just because the raid was mounted.

Comment: As to your first question: I always get emails monthly about inconsistencies from that check. Apparently the check does not take into account what blocks are just being written to; I'm assuming that would make the check quite a bit slower. I mainly use the check to ensure that all disk blocks are still readable, otherwise if a block silenty goes bad, and the other half of the raid1 fails, you have data loss. On raid5 it can often be corrected by a rewite of the block.

Comment: This seems to be the only way I've found to do this, yet on my system `/sys/block/md126/md/sync_action` does not exist? If I try to execute this anyways under a root shell (`sudo su`), I get *Permission denied*. Any ideas?

Comment: This command terminates instantly afterwards, it's not clear where the results can be observed afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Debian or Ubuntu you can run the `checkarray` script:

```
/usr/share/mdadm/checkarray /dev/mdX
```

Where `mdX` above is your array device.

Remember to unmount the filesystem first.

*Note, that the inconvenience of remembering and / or writing the whole path to the script can be easily avoided by e.g. defining an alias.*

Comment: unmounting is most certainly not needed. see comment here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238055/how-to-to-verify-any-mdadm-raid-array-is-doing-fine#comment838747_238083